# Display related terms from a taxonomy in an entry

Tags: taxonomy

I have a function to obtain specific taxonomies in each entry. The problem is, for each entry, it shows all the values that the taxonomy contains. How can I do to show the correct value to each entry?
I don't know about programming. I appreciate you being clear in the answer. Thank you

```
  $terms = get_terms( ( array('taxonomy' => 'dormitorio', 'hide_empty' => false,)));

    if ( isset( $terms ) && '' !== $terms ) {
        foreach( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<div class="tax dormitorio ' . $term->slug . '">';
            echo $term->name;
            echo '</div>';
        }
```

Comment: I have it inside functions.php
How can I use get_the_terms()?  I changed it and I 've got differents error.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify where are you using the code above, if in a template file or in a function.
Assuming the code above is for a single post and that you're trying to retrieve the `dormitorio` terms associated with that post you should use `get_the_terms()` instead of `get_terms()`.

[get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) Retrieves the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies

whilst

[get_the_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) Retrieves the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution:

```
    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'dormitorio' );

if ( isset( $terms ) && '' !== $terms ) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
        echo '<div class="tax dormitorio ' . $term->slug . '">';
        echo $term->name;
        echo '</div>';
        }
    }
```